# Retrieve first tweet for a given keyword

Tags: api, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-search

Is it possible to find first tweet for a given keyword?

Example: Let i have to find first tweet for "Storm" keyword. Then Url should return the first tweet of this keyword.

Comment: I'm thinking that this question might be a candidate for flagging as 'too broad'.

Answer (score 0):

The first tweet on history?
 You can't do that with the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search), but maybe you could with a paid service like [Gnip](https://gnip.com/sources/twitter/historical/)